# Group csv data into json using Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have never used Pandas before and i'm trying to do a very simple conversion from csv data to json.

My csv data is of the form:

```
Category | Type | Parameter Name | Parameter Value
---------|------|----------------|----------------
Windows  | W1   | Width          | 900
Windows  | W1   | Height         | 900
Windows  | W2   | Width          | 1200
Windows  | W2   | Height         | 500
Doors    | D1   | Width          | 900
Doors    | D1   | Height         | 2100
Doors    | D2   | Width          | 820
Doors    | D2   | Height         | 2100
```

And I want to produce something like:

```
{
    "Windows": {
        "W1": {
            "Height": 900, 
            "Width": 900
         }, 
         "W2": {
             "Height": 500, 
             "Width": 1200
         },
     },
     "Doors: {
        "D1": {
            "Height": 2100, 
            "Width": 900
         }, 
         "D2": {
             "Height": 2100, 
             "Width": 500
         }, 
     }, 
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Pandas DataFrame has functions read_csv() and to_json().

Comment: Yeah i'm OK with converting the csv to a dataframe but not sure how to group it into the nested format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't have time to do more.  Hope this helps

```
s = df.set_index(df.columns[:-1].tolist())[df.columns[-1]]

def redict(s):
    if s.index.nlevels == 1:
        return s.to_dict()
    else:
        return {k: redict(g.xs(k)) for k, g in s.groupby(level=0)}

redict(s)

{'Doors': {'D1': {'Height': 2100, 'Width': 900},
  'D2': {'Height': 2100, 'Width': 820}},
 'Windows': {'W1': {'Height': 900, 'Width': 900},
  'W2': {'Height': 500, 'Width': 1200}}}
```

---

And with a slight modification, we get `json`

```
s = df.set_index(df.columns[:-1].tolist())[df.columns[-1]]

def redict(s):
    if s.index.nlevels == 1:
        return s.astype(str).to_dict()
    else:
        return {k: redict(g.xs(k)) for k, g in s.groupby(level=0)}

json.dumps(redict(s))

'{"Doors": {"D1": {"Width": "900", "Height": "2100"}, "D2": {"Width": "820", "Height": "2100"}}, "Windows": {"W1": {"Width": "900", "Height": "900"}, "W2": {"Width": "1200", "Height": "500"}}}'
```